# python error: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.timedelta") to str

Tags: python

i am trying to get the weeks between two dates and split into rows by week and here is the error message i got:

**can only concatenate str (not "datetime.timedelta") to str**
Can anyone help on this one? thanks!!!

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd


df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xx.csv')
print(df)

# Convert dtaframe to dates
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])

df_out = pd.DataFrame()

week = 7

# Iterate over dataframe rows

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    date = row["start_date"]
    date_end = row["end_date"]
    dealtype = row["deal_type"]
    ppg = row["PPG"]
    # Get the weeks for the row
    while date < date_end:
        date_next = date + datetime.timedelta(week - 1)
        df_out = df_out.append([[dealtype, ppg, date, date_next]])
        date = date_next + datetime.timedelta(1)

# Remove extra index and assign columns as original dataframe

df_out = df_out.reset_index(drop=True)
df_out.columns = df.columns
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Output.csv', index=None)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Answer (score 2):

`date` is a Timestamp object which is later converted to a datetime.timedelta object.

`datetime.timedelta(week - 1)` is a datetime.timedelta object.

Both of these objects can be converted to a string by using `str()`.

If you want to concatenate the string, simply wrap it with `str()`

```py
date_next = str(date) + str(datetime.timedelta(week - 1))
```

Comment: This is helpful, but i tried adding in the str() to the datetime.timedelta object and get this error message instead... date_next = date + str(datetime.timedelta(week - 1))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'str'

Comment: The question is not "how can I concatenate 2 strings" but, "why am I getting this error about string concatenation when I want to apply some timedelta to a datetime object"

Answer (score 1):

You converted the `start_date` and `end_date` column to datetime, but you added the converted columns as `Start Date` and `End Date`.  Then, in the loop, you fetch `row["start_date"]`, which is still a string.  If you want to REPLACE the `start_date` column, then don't give it a new name.  Spelling matters.